# To which prophets does Peter refer in 1 Peter 1:10-11?

Tags: prophets

To which prophecies does Peter refer in these verses?

1 Peter 1:10,11:

> 10 Of which salvation the prophets have enquired and searched
>   diligently, who prophesied of the grace that should come unto you:
>
> 11 Searching what, or what manner of time the Spirit of Christ which
>   was in them did signify, when it testified beforehand the sufferings
>   of Christ, and the glory that should follow.

I'm looking for scriptures of prophets telling about the grace that should come unto us. I'd like to see the cross reference between the old and new testament. 
I know the verses in Isaiah, but I'm looking for one or two more references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

King David in Psalm 22

> Psa 22:15-18  My strength is dried up like a potsherd; and my tongue
>   cleaveth to my jaws; and thou hast brought me into the dust of death. 
>   (16)  For dogs have compassed me: the assembly of the wicked have
>   inclosed me: they **pierced my hands and my feet.**  (17)  I may tell all
>   my bones: they look and stare upon me.  (18)  They part my garments
>   among them, and cast lots upon my vesture.

and less directly

> Psa 2:1-3  Why do the heathen rage, and the people imagine a vain
>   thing?  (2)  The kings of the earth set themselves, and the rulers
>   take counsel together, against the LORD, and **against his anointed**,
>   saying,  (3)  Let us break their bands asunder, and cast away their
>   cords from us.